# How to display all release and support branches on the bamboo wallboard

Tags: bamboo

We are starting to use Bamboo to monitor our builds, and we have started to use the "branches" facility from the build plans. These work great, except for one thing, on the wallboard, only the "main" build status is shown, not the status of the branches. Given that our branches are also release branches, we would like to see the status of the main branch and all of the "release" branches, but not the "hot fix", "feature", or "bug fix" branches.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a label:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/displaying-the-wallboard-289276971.html

Also there is this:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html#Usingplanbranches-wallboard

But it looks like the wallboard is a bit of an unloved feature - they have some feature requests still open for it with a lot of watchers/votes that haven't been touched in three years or more.

You could also probably just implement your own wallboard and use the REST API to get statuses - the UI for wallboards is not very complex, and having your own javascript code accessing the REST API would give you complete control.